# Combining multiple Rows values into a single columns.

Tags: mysql

> This is the table structure output

[image: first image]

> I want to merge all the package and component, with output like below:

[image: second image]

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Does the order of the components in the output matter to you?

Comment: Yes as it is being linked to the date when it was entered. so it should be either in ASC by id or DESC by id

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear - I meant is there a business rule which says columns should be in the order water,air,fire rather than air,fire,water (for example)?

Comment: Order can be in any way just the value of water shouldn't go to air or air value shouldn't go to water column. And the component which i have taken water , air & fire are dynamic based on the package no, So in some where it might be 2 component or some where might be 4 or 5 accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE statement, it will resolve you issue only when number of component is fix

```
SELECT package, 
(CASE WHEN COMPONENT = 'WATER' THEN MARKS END) AS WATER,
(CASE WHEN COMPONENT = 'AIR' THEN MARKS END) AS AIR,
(CASE WHEN COMPONENT = 'FIRE' THEN MARKS END) AS FIRE
FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: That component will be dynamic, but i tried with two component, i am getting output only package, the component and marks are not getting displayed.

Comment: @RiteshSharma I can't believe, can you share output and query.

Comment: I resolved the error, but the output is something like this.

Comment: `04YGR01House Service Connection0.000
04YGR01Distribution Network0.150
04YGR01House Service Connection0.000
04YGR01Distribution Network0.130
04YGR01House Service Connection0.000
04YGR01Distribution Network0.060`

Comment: @RiteshSharma are you using MySQL ?? or something else

Comment: Yes i am using  MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You need just to [PIVOT](http://codingsight.com/pivot-tables-in-mysql/) the table. It gives a little bit another presentation, but try this one -

```
SELECT
  t.Package,
  MAX(IF(t.Component = 'WATER', t.Marks, NULL)) AS Water,
  MAX(IF(t.Component = 'AIR', t.Marks, NULL)) AS Air,
  MAX(IF(t.Component = 'FIRE', t.Marks, NULL)) AS Fire
FROM
  table t
GROUP BY
  t.Package;
```

Comment: That Component will be  dynamic its not fixed to 3 component. For considering the example i have included three component.

Comment: <?php
 
include 'connect-db.php';
$query = "SELECT t.package_no, MAX(IF(t.work_component = '$work_component', t.daily_progress, NULL)) AS Sewer FROM daily_progress_demo t  WHERE package_no='$package_no' GROUP BY t.package_no ;"; 
   
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo $row['package_no'];
   
  echo $row['work_component'];
 
  echo $row['daily_progress'];
 
}
?>

Comment: I have run your code its only displaying me the package details, component and marks<->daily_progress. Its giving error. Undefined index

Comment: You can make this query dynamic. Have a look at this point - http://codingsight.com/pivot-tables-in-mysql/#automating. Try to test the query without php firstly, the query must be tested and checked.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the row the component appears on depends on the order it appears in table you could work out the row number for a concatenated psuedo key and then apply a group by

```
/*
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T (ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,PACKAGE VARCHAR(10),COMPONENT VARCHAR(10), MARKS INT);

INSERT INTO T (PACKAGE,COMPONENT,MARKS) VALUES
('02ABC','WATER',20),('02ABC','WATER',15),('02ABC','AIR',16),('02ABC','AIR',18),('02ABC','AIR',6),
('02ABC','WATER',5),
('02MNO','WATER',10),('02MNO','AIR',5),('02MNO','FIRE',15);
*/

SELECT S.PACKAGE,
         #S.OCCURANCE,
         MAX(CASE WHEN S.COMPONENT = 'WATER' THEN S.MARKS ELSE 0 END) WATER,
         MAX(CASE WHEN S.COMPONENT = 'AIR' THEN S.MARKS ELSE 0 END) AIR,
         MAX(CASE WHEN S.COMPONENT = 'FIRE' THEN S.MARKS ELSE 0 END) FIRE
FROM
(
SELECT T.ID,T.PACKAGE,T.COMPONENT,T.MARKS,
         IF(CONCAT(T.PACKAGE,T.COMPONENT) <> @P ,@OCCURANCE:=1,@OCCURANCE:=@OCCURANCE+1) OCCURANCE,
         @P:=CONCAT(T.PACKAGE,T.COMPONENT) P
FROM (SELECT @OCCURANCE:=0,@P:='') O,T
ORDER BY T.PACKAGE,T.COMPONENT,T.ID
) S
GROUP BY S.PACKAGE,S.OCCURANCE
```